# Android: How to create a List Item / Grid Item Overflow

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

Does anyone how how to create an overflow item like those in Google Play?
One idea I have is to just use a Spinner with a background and fixed width but I was wondering if there was a better way. Below is a screenshot of the kind of overflow menu on grid items that I have in mind.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PopupMenu. It will give you desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

The one you can use is [`QuickActionView`](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) which is as per your requirement. One of the interesting pattern is **QuickActions** that displays contextual actions in a list view.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great tip but not what I was looking for!